# Rails: Organising a row with partial :collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, math, partial-views

Ok so I am rendering a partial:

```
<%= render :partial => "box", :collection => @dashboard.charts %>
```

In the partial I am organising each "box" into rows of 3. Like this:

```
if box_counter % 3 == 0 && box_counter != 0
    %></div><div class='row'><%
end
```

which works great.

Here is my problem. I got my maths down but I'm not sure how to translate it into Ruby. Let me explain.

Each Box has a size. Small, Medium and Large. All sizes have been assigned a width. 20%, 30% and 50%. Which adds up to 100%.

A user can have any arrangement of these boxes in each row. What I need to do is check that the boxes in the row add up to 100%. So if its under or over 100% I will get the difference, divide it by 3 and add or remove that percent to each box therefor making each box add up to 100%.

For example. A user could have a combination of a Large Box, Large Box and then a Small Box. This adds up to 120%. So we get the difference, which is 20%, divide it by 3 = 6.6%, and then remove it from the 3 boxes (cause we went over 100%). So that becomes: LargeBox = 43.4%, LargeBox = 43.4%, Small Box = 13.4%. Which will add up to 100%. (or close to which is fine).

I've been working on this with Ruby and just don't know how to get my maths into the loop or something. Really stuck here guys. I would appreciate the help.

Cheers.

Comment: The way you are organizing rows in your partial is really brittle, I would *not* do it that way. If you want to group your columns into rows, I'd look at something like [`slice`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-slice) or [`group_by`](http://apidock.com/rails/Enumerable/group_by). That would also probably make the math easier.

Comment: p.s. can you show some code from the partial? Are these widths coming from attributes of a `Chart` model?

Comment: Yes. The widths (sizes) are coming form the chart model. E.g. `<div class='box <%=box.size%>'</div>` They are ordered by the user as each box is given a rank. So the combination of sizes per row is unknown. I just need to make each box add up to 100% according to their size.

Comment: @DuckMaestro the ratio is a great idea. Thanks!

Comment: @SolidPink Np. Since you found this useful, I've moved it into an answer form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know Ruby, but since this is also tagged 'math', let me present a slightly different approach to the math that might be easier.

If your sum is 120% (for instance), calculate a ratio of 100%/120% which gives you .833. Then multiply .833 by each of the three individual widths. There's no need to perform three subtractions of different amounts this way. And 100%/100% = 1.0, so this same process still works correctly in either case.